# Technical Specs for Programmers

Tags: documentation

I'm looking for some guidelines on writing a technical spec. This spec will be given to contract programmers for writing the business logic in an application. There is no user interaction in these applications, only application to application interaction. So far I've only been able to find information on writing specifications based on user input. I was thinking that maybe UML would be useful for this, but I'm not sure.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you are looking more for how to write a requirement specification. the actual format depends on how much is already decided and understod by the contracted programmers. Is the platform or language decided upon? Do you have any execution requirements?

Comment: @Gorgen Language is C#, specifically self hosted WCF services. Nothing is currently been explained to the programmers. However they are familiar with WCF and C#. We don't have any formal requirements written at this point, they will be written on the fly. Perhaps it would be best to layout how the application would work first, and then write the requirements based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is; if you doesn't have a lot of time to spend on this make some input/output sketches of the functions combined with UML flow diagrams. If you have time and some money to spend I can recomend "Object-oriented Modelling and Design with UML" by Michael Blaha and James Rumbaugh. read it and apply it on your requirements but instead of going to implementation leave it to the contract programmers. It is more time upfront but less questions later. Hope it helps.